# EF Core Many To Many Duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to setup a many to many relationship using EF Core and ASP.NET Core 2.1 and as for now I cannot get this working and it seems I do not understand the logic behind it either.

So I have setup many to many relationship using ModelBuilder like this:

```
builder.Entity<ComponentWare>().HasKey(cw => new { cw.ComponentId, cw.WareId });
            builder.Entity<ComponentWare>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Component)
                .WithMany(x => x.ComponentWares)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ComponentId);
            builder.Entity<ComponentWare>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Ware)
                .WithMany(x => x.ComponentWares)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.WareId);


            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

My entity models:

```
public class Component
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MaterialType { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
    public sbyte ComponentType { get; set; }
    public sbyte SourceType { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookComponent> BookComponents { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentWare> ComponentWares { get; set; } 
}

public class Ware
{
    public int WareId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal? Converter { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentWare> ComponentWares { get; set; }
}
```

And my join table:

```
public class ComponentWare
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }

    public int WareId { get; set; }
    public Ware Ware { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Length { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

}
```

Now, I want to setup a many to many relationship between Ware and Component tables so that in the end my join table would look like this.

```
Tables:   WareId    |   ComponentId    |        ComponentWares         |
            1       |      1           | ComponentId  |      WareId    |
            2       |      2           |      1       |        1       |
                                       |      1       |        1       |
                                       |      2       |        1       |
                                       |      2       |        1       |
```

So many components could have many wares ( also duplicated ) and vice versa.

I have tried to manually add entries using SQL Server Explorer but it seems I cannot add multiple ComponentId and WareId with the same values because of the

```
HasKey(cw => new { cw.ComponentId, cw.WareId })
```

I've read that the line above is necessary for many to many relationship in EF Core but for my understanding it denies the idea of many to many relationship...

Should I remove **ComponentId cw.WareId** key from the ModelBuilder and add Id in the join table or is the another solution for this ?

Comment: Why do you need duplicated rows in `ComponentWares`?

Comment: `Should I remove ComponentId cw.WareId key from the ModelBuilder and add Id in the join table or is the another solution for this ?` Yes! If you need duplicated rows then you have to do this.

Comment: For many-to-many relationship, you should not add the same value for `ComponentId` and `WareId`. I assume there is something wrong in your query, share us your original data, and expected query result for these tables.

Comment: @TaoZhou Every **Component** contains several **Ware** items. For example: Component number "042.04" is made of several wares: {"Profile 30x30", "Angle bar 10x20x2"} and so on. I just want to store this kind of information in my database. There will be multiple Components with similar Ware items [Example](https://imgur.com/a/oi5zrjD) Is there any other way to store such information other than in the many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

For your expected result, you should define it with many-to-many relationship.

Your original issue is caused by inserting duplex value in the middle table.

You should insert the records below to `ComponentWares`

[image]